# Matlab's std works in REPL but not in the programm

Tags: matlab

I wanted to calculate the standard derivation of the elements of a matrix. So i first transformed my matrix with the command `reshape` to a vector, and then used `std`.

However, I got a error message:

```
Error using var (line 59)
First argument must be single or double.

Error in std (line 32)
y = sqrt(var(varargin{:}));

Error in reducenoise2>standabw (line 112)
            s = std(B);

Error in reducenoise2 (line 36)
 D = standabw(n,m,r,fu,D);
```

So I printed my vector `B`, just before passing it to `std`. I assigned it to a variable `x` in REPL tried calling `std(x)` manually.

Interestingly enough, this works just fine.

So how can the function `std` – called with the same arguments – result in an error when used within my code, but work fine in REPL?

Here is the Matlab function:

```
function [D] = standabw(n,m,r,fu,D)
    for i = 1+r:n-r
        for j = 1+r:m-r
            C = D(i-r:i+r,j-r:j+r);
            B = reshape(C,(2*r+1)^2,1)
            s = std(B);
            if s > fu
                D(i,j) = 255;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This is the vector `B`, just before the error message:

```
B =

    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    1
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely your B vector its of some int type. Try to call this way

```
std(double(B))
```

The above statement first casts `B` to double type, and then calls std.

To check, what is the type of the variables type `whos` at the command prompt.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. But I still don't understand why. Would you mind explaining this?

Comment: Simple: it's expecting doubles as input.